# Overload the stream insertion operator for nested structures/classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the stream insertion operator for a structure nested within a class. How can I fix this error and make the function to work, or is there any alternative method to implement it?

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
};

class T {
private:
    S** arrayName;
    int r;
    int c;

public:
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& _os, const T& _t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _t.r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _t.c; j++) {
                _os << _t.arrayName[i][j];
            }
        }
        return _os;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to overload it for S too.

Comment: after overloading it for S , how i am gonna implement it (Same as for T / differently)?

Comment: @UncleMarvin your implementation in `T` is fine, you just need a 2nd implementation for `S` that outputs `a` and `b`, then the `_os << _t.arrayName[i][j]` statement will be able to use it, eg: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& _os, const S& _s) { _os << _s.a << ' ' << _s.b << endl; return _os; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `arrayName` was just an integer array within `class T` like:

```
int arrayName [4][4]; //for example
```

the current implementation would work. But as `arrayName` is a pointer to pointer to `struct S` and acts as a two-dimensional array of `struct S`, you will need to overload the `<<` operator within `struct S` to be able to print its members `a` and `b`.

So your `struct S` should now be:

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& _os, const S& _s) { 
        _os << _s.a << ' ' << _s.b << endl; 
        return _os; 
    }
};
```